# Can a neutron act as a wave? Can the wave of light superpose with the wave of neutrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, superposition, wave-particle-duality, neutrons

Can neutrons act as a wave? and can that wave superpose with wave of a photon? and what are, if any, the required conditions for that phenomenon to happen? Thirdly, if we pass light through completely ionised atoms (or nuclei), will the light diffract?

Comment: Where did you get these question from?

Comment: Neutron diffraction is a fine experimental technique, so, yes, they can act like waves.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Neutrons can be easily manipulated into circumstances in which they exhibit wavelengths, and can be diffracted.

Photons interact most strongly with charged particles, but will also interact with neutral particles which possess a magnetic moment, which the neutron does. This effect appears at high energies; most of the time the photon scatters off the neutron.